# Show that $\det \rho(g)=1$ for elements g of odd order and $\det \rho(g)=-1$ for elements g of even order.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, solution-verification

$G$ is a finite group.

> $\rho$ is a representation of $G$, then $\rho \mapsto \rho(g)$ is a $1$-dimensional representation.
>
> Show that if $\det \rho(g)=-1$ for some $g \in G$ then $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $2$.

I believe this is because

$$1=(-1)^2=(\det \rho(g))^2=\det \rho(g)\det \rho(g)=\det \rho(g^2)$$

so $g \in \ker(\det \rho)$, $\det \rho$ is clearly a homomorphism. So noticing

$$\det \rho(g^{odd number})=-1$$

and

$$\det \rho(g^{even number})=1 $$

so $\langle g^2 \rangle$ generates a subgroup which is normal index $2$.

> Now suppose $|G|=2k$, $k$ odd, let $\rho=\mathbb{C}[G]$ be the regular representation of $G$. Show that $\det \rho(g)=1$ for elements g of odd order and $\det \rho(g)=-1$ for elements g of even order.

I cannot see how to start this because as far as I know $\mathbb{C}[G]$ isn't written as a matrix, nor can I see how to determine the order of its elements for the general case.

Comment: $\rho(g)$ is the permutation matrix of $g$ in the regular permutation representation of $G$. The matrix $\rho(g)$ has determinant $-1$ iff the permutation is odd iff $g$ has even order.

Comment: @DerekHolt This is confusing to me as I have it is the permutation matrix when $\pi: G \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C}[X])$, $G$ acting on $\mathbb{C}[X]$, but the regular representation is just $\{ \alpha_g g \mid g \in G\}$. I cannot see how this can be.

Comment: It's false in general, you have to assume that $G$ is a finite group (finitely generated is enough too).

Comment: @YCor Apologies, I only put it with the tag finite groups

Comment: @sandstone: Your solution seems not to be true. Yo only showed that $<g^2>$ has index $2$ in $<g>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi=det\ p(g)$ then $\phi:G\to \mathbb C^*$ be a homomorphism. Note that $\phi(G)$ is an finite abelian  group. Since $\phi(g)=-1$ for some $g$, $|\phi(G)|$ is even.

Notice that any abelian group of even order has subgroup of index $2$. Now, $\phi(G)$ has subgroup $H$ of index $2$. You can see that $\phi(H)^{-1}$ has index $2$ in $G$.

For second question,

$\mathbb C[G]$ is an $G$ module and $G$ itself is a base of this vector space.

Let $x$ be a element of order $2$ in $G$. Notice that $x$ has permutation representatin on $G$ by $x=(g_1,xg_1)(g_2,xg_2)... (g_k,xg_k)$. As $x$ act on $G$ by permutaion, it acts on $\mathbb C[G]$.

Notice that the matrice representatin of $x$ with base $G$ is $[x]_G$ which is a degenerate version of identity matrix with $k$ cloum changes. Hence $det([x]_G)=(-1)^k$. As $k$ is odd we are done.